# Javascript - Select drop down element with target value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down box with values dynamically populated from a database.  So, its HTML is somewhat like this:

```
<select id="productclass">
    <option value="1">Name1</option>
    <option value="7">Name2</option>
    <option value="11">Name11</option>
</select>
```

Where the id's and the names are pulled from the database.

I need to be able to write JavaScript to select the option with a specific value.  So, how can I make option #7 selected using JavaScript?  I can use JQuery too if it's easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the option with value 7, use:

```
document.getElementById("productclass").value = "7";
$("#productclass").val("7");                         //jQuery
```

If you mean option number 7 by "`#7`", use:

```
document.getElementById("productclass").selectedIndex = 6;
// Indexes are zero-based, the 7th element is referred through index 6
```

Comment: [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7hrmS/) (of the second method: this is how I read the question).

Comment: You can and should use the value instead of the index. The `document.getElementById("productclass").value = 7` will work just fine.

Comment: @liho1eye Have a look at the final phrase at the question. `option #7` can be interpreted as `option number seven`. I have included answers for both interpretations: Option with *value* 7, or option *number* 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery:

```
$('#productclass').val('7');
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/gwRD4/)